# adding uilabel on uiimage showing on uitable view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am adding label to uiimage and then adding that image on uitable view. but it is not showing. Can anyone help please?

This is code i am using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    }
//image which contains label
    UIImageView *BgImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-bg.png"]];
    BgImage.frame=cell.frame;
//label which will be on image
    UILabel *NameLAbel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 5, 45, 45)];


    NameLAbel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        NameLAbel.text=@"Home";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row==1) {
        NameLAbel.text=@"You";
    }
   else if (indexPath.row==2) {
        NameLAbel.text=@"Contacts";
    }
    else if (indexPath.row==3) {
        NameLAbel.text=@"Settings";
    }
    else {
        NameLAbel.text=@"Sign Out";
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",NameLAbel.text);

    [BgImage addSubview:NameLAbel];
//adding image on cell
    [cell.contentView addSubview:BgImage];


   [NameLAbel release];
    [BgImage release];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is it that just the label isn't showing? or is nothing showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can actually add a `UILabel` to an `UIImageView`, although they are both `UIView` subclasses, I think the imageview will only display the image.

try adding the label to `cell.contentView` after you've added the image to the view. That should achieve the affect you are after.

Either that, or create of `UIView` which will hold both the `UIImageView` and the `UILabel`

Comment: OK my bad. Although, adding the label to contentView should still achieve what the OP is after. Unless I'm missing something from his code.

Comment: @sunajledif: it might be possible but nevertheless UIImageView is an exception between UIView classes. For example, if you sublass it and set its `needsDisplay` to `YES` that won't result in `drawRect:` being called as one would expect. So Amit and Bogatyr have a point here. It can hold subviews though - that is also true.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some UI widget as a subview of a UIImageView sounds really questionable.   Even if it works now it may not work in the future, and I believe this breaks the UIKit convention.  If you want to make one view look like it is "part of" another view, place the two as siblings, either directly in the cell.contentView as Amit noted, or if you want clipping so that the label looked like it was being clipped by the image, create a UIView container, enable the "clip subviews" setting of  that view, and place the UIImageView and UILabel as siblings within that container UIView.